# wp_title showing page title but not site title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-4.0

I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere and I have a hard time believing I'm the only one who has had this problem.

My title function inside my title tag of *header.php*, `<?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>`, is returning the page title but not the site title.

Example: `About Us |`

Why would it not be returning the site name??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried combining the entire title inside one function. Instead I use multiple calls:

`<?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' |'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>`

Comment: Here's what I used that's a little simpler:
<?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?> <?php=bloginfo('name') ?>

Answer (score 4):

Looks like wp_title() does not return the site's title.  Sorry, hopefully someone will benefit from this answer.

Comment: I did benefit from it. Thanks!